# ggplot2 in shiny, change then reload image/plot without completely recreating it

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, shiny

I'm making an app with `shiny` which will allow users to click to select points on an image. I'm using `ggplot2` to display the points as they're selected, as red dots on the image.

I have this working pretty close to the way I want, except that every time the user clicks a new point, the entire image gets reloaded*. Ideally, I'd be re-plotting the data each click, but not reloading the entire image.

My question is, is it possible to have the plot points reload reactively, but leave the background image alone (since it won't change between clicks)?

My actual app is more involved than this, but here is my best attempt at a minimal reproducible example of the issue I'd like to address (note you'll need to adjust `image.file` to point to a jpg file on your machine in order to run this; I don't know how to make the image itself reproducible, sorry):

```
library( ggplot2 )
library( jpeg )
library( grid )
library( shiny )

#### pre-run setup ####

# set up a function for loading an image file as a grob
grob_image <- function( file ) {
    grid::rasterGrob( jpeg::readJPEG( file ), interpolate = TRUE )
}

# initiate a ggplot theme for use in plotting
# (just getting rid of everything so we only see the image itself)
theme_empty <- theme_bw()
theme_empty$line <- element_blank()
theme_empty$rect <- element_blank()
theme_empty$strip.text <- element_blank()
theme_empty$axis.text <- element_blank()
theme_empty$plot.title <- element_blank()
theme_empty$axis.title <- element_blank()

# set the image input file
image.file <- "session2_ebbTriggerCountMap.jpg"

#### UI ####
ui <- fluidPage(

    # display the image, with any click-points
    fluidRow(
        plotOutput("plot",
                   click = "image_click"
        )
    )

)


### SERVER ####
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # initialise a data.frame for collecting click points
    data.thisimage <- data.frame( x = rep( NA_real_, 100L ), y = rep( NA_real_, 100L ) )

    # initalise the plot (this is the image on which to put any points we get)
    # the `geom_blank` here is to set up the x and y axes as per the width and height of the image
    img <- grob_image( image.file )
    base <- ggplot() +
        geom_blank( data = data.frame( x = c( 0, dim( img$raster )[2] ), y = c( 0, dim( img$raster )[1] ) ),
                    mapping = aes( x = x, y = y )
        ) +
        theme_empty +
        annotation_custom( grob = img )

    # plot the image
    output$plot <- renderPlot( {
        base
    } )

    #### click action ####
    # watch for a mouse click (point selected on the plot)
    observeEvent( input$image_click, {

        # add a row of data to the data frame
        data.thisimage[ which( is.na( data.thisimage$x ) )[1L], ] <<- c(
            input$image_click$x, input$image_click$y
        )

        # re-render the plot with the new data
        output$plot <<- renderPlot( {
            base +
                geom_point( data = data.thisimage[ !is.na( data.thisimage$x ), ],
                            mapping = aes( x = as.numeric( x ), y = as.numeric( y ) ),
                            colour = "red" )
        } )

    } )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Since the image gets reloaded with every mouse click, I'm anticipating problems with reactivity of the UI, CPU load, and data transfer load. Is there any way to alleviate that?

* it's probably obvious from the code itself, but I've proved it to myself by watching CPU load while clicking over and over again with a large-ish image loaded.

NOTE the closest I could find to my problem was this SO question. Unfortunately it doesn't resolve the issue of reloading the image, only speeding up the rendering of data points, which is not my problem here. [Update large plots in Shiny without Re-Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232780/update-large-plots-in-shiny-without-re-rendering)

Comment: FYI I get `Error in img$raster : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` when trying to run this

Comment: Sorry, that's my bad. I've neglected to make a change when I made the example "minimal", I've made a change, and it should work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try first to suggest a shorter version of the code, to make sure which part is the heavy one.

- I took base <- ggplot() out of the server as it depends on static values, and could be executed once.
- I created xy_coord() capture the click x-y coordinates.
- I used  shinySignals::reducePast to add the values to a dataframe xy_click(). **Note**: *shinySignals is still under development, so you can write the function yourself if you would like.*
- Now, I assume your problem is with having `base` in renderPlot, right?

  `output$plot <- renderPlot({
      base +
        geom_point(...)
    })`

In the **Updated Solution** :

- In the UI, I created two divs on top of each other inside div "container", *the bottom for the jpeg image and 2nd for the points.*
- I plotted the jpeg image once at the bottom `output$plot`
- I used the click option`click="image$click"` the 2nd plot `output$plot1`, which will be rendered every time, because it is on the top.
- I used `bg="transparent"` option to have the image visible in the background.

**EXTRA**

You could even avoid using `output$plot <- renderPlot(...)` by moving the image to `www` folder in the app folder AND  embedding the image in the first `div` using `tags$img`

```
| shinyApp/
    | app.R
| www/
    | survey.jpg
```

**NOTE: This should work in case of perfect alignment of both image and plot2, I haven't tested intensively, but i tried  a couple of examples.**

---

**Updated Solution**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)
library(shiny)

#### pre-run setup ####

# initiate a ggplot theme for use in plotting
# (just getting rid of everything so we only see the image itself)
theme_empty <- theme_bw()
theme_empty$line <- element_blank()
theme_empty$rect <- element_blank()
theme_empty$strip.text <- element_blank()
theme_empty$axis.text <- element_blank()
theme_empty$plot.title <- element_blank()
theme_empty$axis.title <- element_blank()

# set the image input file
image.file <- "www/survey.jpg"

img <- jpeg::readJPEG(image.file)

## set up a function for loading an image file as a grob ---------------------
# grob_image <- function(file) {
#   grid::rasterGrob( jpeg::readJPEG(file), interpolate = TRUE )
# }

## load the image as a a grob ---------------------
# img <- grob_image(image.file)

#### UI ####
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Overlapping images in 2 divs inside a "container"
  fluidRow(
    div(id="container",
        height = dim(img)[1],
        width = dim(img)[2],
        style="position:relative;",
        div(tags$img(src='survey.jpg',
                     style=paste0("width:",dim(img)[2],";height:",dim(img)[2],";")),
          # plotOutput("plot",
          #              height = dim(img)[1],
          #              width = dim(img)[2],
          #              click = "image_cl1"),
            style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"),
        div(plotOutput("plot1",
                       height = dim(img)[1],
                       width = dim(img)[2],
                       click = "image_click"),
            style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;")
    )
  )
)

### SERVER ####
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ## get clicked point coordinates -----------------------
  xy_coord <- reactive(c(input$image_click$x,input$image_click$y))

  ## add the new points to the dataframe -----------------
  xy_clicks <- shinySignals::reducePast(xy_coord,
                                        function(x,y){
                                          df <- x
                                          nn <- nrow(df)

                                          # add values in case of click
                                          if(length(y)>0){
                                            df[nn+1,1 ] <- y[1]
                                            df[nn+1,2 ] <- y[2]
                                          }
                                          return(df)
                                        },
                                        init=data.frame(x_coord=numeric(0),
                                                        y_coord=numeric(0)))

  ## render plot of the jpeg image --------------------------------------
  # output$plot <- renderPlot({
  #   ggplot()+
  #     geom_blank(data = data.frame(x = c(0, dim(img$raster)[2])
  #                                  , y = c(0, dim(img$raster)[1])),
  #                mapping = aes(x = x, y = y))+
  #     theme_empty +
  #     annotation_custom(grob = img)
  # })

  # alternative for plot of the jpeg image
  # output$plot <- renderPlot({
  #   # plot_jpeg("survey.jpg")
  # })


  ## re-render the plot with the new data -------------------------
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot() +
      geom_blank(data = data.frame(x = c(0,dim(img)[2])
                                   ,y = c(0,dim(img)[1])),
                 mapping = aes(x = x,
                               y = y))+
      theme_empty+
      geom_point(data = xy_clicks(),
                 mapping = aes(x = x_coord,
                               y = y_coord),
                 colour = "red")+
      coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,dim(img)[2]),
                      ylim= c(0,dim(img)[1]))

  },
  bg="transparent")

}


## uncomment and add verbatimTextOutput("txt") in UI to see the xy_clicks() dataframe
# output$txt <- renderPrint(xy_clicks())

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

**My version of the original code**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(jpeg)
library(grid)
library(shiny)

#### pre-run setup ####

# set up a function for loading an image file as a grob
grob_image <- function( file ) {
  grid::rasterGrob( jpeg::readJPEG( file ), interpolate = TRUE )
}

# initiate a ggplot theme for use in plotting
# (just getting rid of everything so we only see the image itself)
theme_empty <- theme_bw()
theme_empty$line <- element_blank()
theme_empty$rect <- element_blank()
theme_empty$strip.text <- element_blank()
theme_empty$axis.text <- element_blank()
theme_empty$plot.title <- element_blank()
theme_empty$axis.title <- element_blank()

# set the image input file
image.file <- "survey.jpg"


## initalise the plot (this is the image on which to put any points we get)
# the `geom_blank` here is to set up the x and y axes as per the width and height of the image 
img <- grob_image(image.file)

## create base plot -----------------------
base <- ggplot() +
  geom_blank(data = data.frame(x = c(0, dim( img$raster )[2])
                                 , y = c(0, dim( img$raster )[1])),
              mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)
  ) +
  theme_empty +annotation_custom(grob = img)


#### UI ####
ui <- fluidPage(

  # display the image, with any click-points
  fluidRow(
    plotOutput("plot",
               height = dim( img$raster )[1],
               width = dim( img$raster )[2],
               click = "image_click"
    )
  )
)

### SERVER ####
server <- function(input, output, session) {


  ## get clicked point coordinates -----------------------
  xy_coord <- reactive(c(input$image_click$x,input$image_click$y))

  ## add the new points to the dataframe -----------------
  xy_clicks <- shinySignals::reducePast(xy_coord,
                                        function(x,y){
                                          df <- x
                                          nn <- nrow(df)

                                          # add values in case of click
                                          if(length(y)>0){
                                            df[nn+1,1 ] <- y[1]
                                            df[nn+1,2 ] <- y[2]
                                          }

                                          return(df)
                                        },
                                        init=data.frame(x_coord=numeric(0),
                                                        y_coord=numeric(0)))


  ## re-render the plot with the new data -------------------------
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    base +
      geom_point(data = xy_clicks(),
                 mapping = aes(x = x_coord, y = y_coord),
                 colour = "red")
  })

  ## uncomment and add verbatimTextOutput("txt") in UI to see the xy_clicks() dataframe
  # output$txt <- renderPrint(xy_clicks())
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi @OmaymaS, yes, the problem is basically in the `base` call which, since it's in `renderPlot` gets recalled every time the user clicks. That's where the seemingly unnecessary work is being done. The image will stay the same, at least while the user is selecting points, so I'm wondering if it's possible to have that `renderPlot` update with new points data, rather than completely rebuilding the image itself.

Comment: Please check the updated solution. There's a work around, and currently testing.

Comment: Thank you @OmaymaS, this seems like a reasonable method (display the image, then overlay the plot with a transparent background). I'm trying some testing as well, I'll let you know how I go.

Comment: I've integrated your method into my app, and it's working much better now. Thank you so much for the effort, this was a great idea!

Comment: @rosscova You are welcome. glad this helped! I just added another option, avoiding using`output$plot <- renderPlot()` at all, by embedding the background image in the bottom `div` in `UI`

Comment: Thanks @OmaymaS, I don't think that embedding like that would be good for my use: I have a "submit" button, which triggers writing of the data to `.csv`, then refreshing the plot with a new image (ready for clicking by the user). It may be useful for someone else though :)