# R Shiny: create non-reactive background in plotOutput

Tags: r, shiny, background

I'm trying to build a shiny app where I can change a plot interactively. I want the plot to change within miliseconds and as the changes only include the addition of some points this is actually possible.

The reproducible example contains an abstraction of this idea. The first example plots a scatterplot and I can interactively change the number of points. This happens basically immediately. I'll refer to this part of the plot as the "reactive layer".

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sliderInput(inputId = "slider_input", label = "Reactive values:", min = 1, max = 100, value = 10),
  plotOutput(outputId = "plotx")
  
)

quick_server <- function(input, output, session){
    
  output$plotx <- renderPlot({
    
    # reactive layer
    plot(
      x = sample(x = -4:4, size = input$slider_input, replace = T), 
      y = sample(x = -4:4, size = input$slider_input, replace = T)
      )
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = quick_server)
```

The problem is that the plot that I want to change interactively always includes a "slow non reactive layer" of many  datapoints that are unreactive and never change. Due to the size of this data set and `renderPlot()` always replotting it the speed with which I interactively change the "reactive layer" decreases dramatically.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sliderInput(inputId = "slider_input", label = "Reactive values:", min = 1, max = 100, value = 10),
  plotOutput(outputId = "plotx")
  
)

slow_server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  base_data <- reactiveVal(value = data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 200000), y = rnorm(n = 200000)))
  
  output$plotx <- renderPlot({
    
    # slow non reactive layer
    plot(x = base_data()$x, y = base_data()$y)
    
    # reactive layer
    points(
      x = sample(x = -4:4, size = input$slider_input, replace = T),
      y = sample(x = -4:4, size = input$slider_input, replace = T), 
      col = "red", 
      cex = 5, 
      pch = 19
      )
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = slow_server)
```

As the base data and the resulting plot (here a cloud of points) never changes it is quite annyoing that `renderPlot()` always replots everything (both "layers"). Is there a way to "isolate" the plot created from the non reactive data set? Such that the layer that is not reactive is not replotted?

I have already tried to work with ggplot2 and create a steady layer

`big_data_frame <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 200000), y = rnorm(n = 200000))`

`steady_layer <- reactiveVal(value = geom_point(data = big_data_frame, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y))`

And then created the plot like this

```
output$plotx <- renderPlot({

  small_df <- 
   data.frame(
      x = sample(x = -4:4, size = input$slider_input, replace = T),
      y = sample(x = -4:4, size = input$slider_input, replace = T)
    )
  
   ggplot() + 
    steady_layer() +
    geom_point(data = small_df, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y) 
    
})
```

But this doesn't help as it is the replotting process that takes time not creating the ggplot layer itself.

Although I can imagine that the solution might be to create a .png of the big plot and use it as the background of the HTML and CSS for the `output$plotx` by making it a reactive UI I have not managed to manipulate the HTML and CSS successfully.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to keep a part of the plot constantly rendered and add some "light layers" above it reactively, but I would be glad to be wrong. One thing you could do to mitigate this problem is use [caching](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/caching.html), so that for each value, only the first computation is slow. For example, when the input value is 10, it will be long, then you change to 15, it is also long, but if you come back to 10 then the output is instantly shown because it was cached. But as I said, not a true solution

Comment: Also, did you see this question: [ggplot2 in shiny, change then reload image/plot without completely recreating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41995550/ggplot2-in-shiny-change-then-reload-image-plot-without-completely-recreating-it)

Comment: I didn't see this comment before posting the answer. basically the same idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand how `renderPlot` works. It uses the R `png` function first to create a png and then sends it to the client browser. When the data of the plot changes, this png is recreated. So, replot part of the png is not possible. So adding points to an existing plot will always use the time of `slow points + new points`, so under the current shiny mechanism, it is not possible not to recalculate these slow points. A possible option is to use `plotly` with [proxy](https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html) . It is made of HTML and Javascript, so yes, you can do it with partial updating. See the link for details, not repeating here. For my personal experience, it is fast not so fast as milliseconds-level as you want.

So here I have a smart trick for you: why do we update on the same plot? We can use one plot as background and it is slow, but we only render it one time, and we will never touch it again. Then we update another plot that has only a few points and we stack this plot on top of the slow plot.

Here is how:

1. add some CSS tricks to do the stacking
2. rendering the slow plot
3. rendering the the quick plot with transparency

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
ui <- fluidPage(
    
    sliderInput(inputId = "slider_input", label = "Reactive values:", min = 1, max = 100, value = 10),
    div(
        class = "large-plot",
        plotOutput(outputId = "plot_bg"),
        plotOutput(outputId = "plotx")
    ),
    tags$style(
        "
        .large-plot {
            position: relative;
        }
        #plot_bg {
            position: absolute;
        }        
        #plotx {
            position: absolute;
        }
        "
    )
    
    
)

slow_server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    base_data <- reactiveVal(value = data.frame(x = rnorm(n = 200000), y = rnorm(n = 200000)))
    
    output$plot_bg <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(base_data()) +
            geom_point(aes(x,y)) +
            scale_x_continuous(breaks = -4:4) +
            scale_y_continuous(breaks = -4:4) +
            xlim(-5, 5) +
            ylim(-5, 5)
    })
    output$plotx <- renderPlot({
        data.frame(
            x = sample(x = -4:4, size = input$slider_input, replace = T),
            y = sample(x = -4:4, size = input$slider_input, replace = T)
        ) %>% 
            ggplot() +
                geom_point(aes(x,y), color = "red", size = 3) + 
                scale_x_continuous(breaks = -4:4) +
                scale_y_continuous(breaks = -4:4) +
            theme(
                panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
                plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA), 
                panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                legend.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"), 
                legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent")
            )+
            xlim(-5, 5) +
            ylim(-5, 5)
    }, bg="transparent")
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = slow_server)
```

[image]

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much!!! :) Just for my understanding: The CSS code #blot_bg... and #plotx is not executed, right? The only relevant code is the .large-plot part?

Comment: Hello Iz100, I've incorporated your solution. Thanks again. I is exactly what I was looking for. Due to the design of the app I'm now running into a different problem regarding the positioning of other elements. I've asked the question [here}(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71219401/r-shiny-css-relative-and-absolute-positioning-of-divs). As you seem to be quite skilled in CSS I assume that this easy to answer for you. I'd really appreciate if you'd take a look. Thank you so much!

Comment: @kuecki95 you do need `#plot_bg` and `#plotx` in CSS, otherwise, two plots will not stack